# Java Springboot : Mapping BDTO to entity using modelMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, modelmapper

**after mapping  i have a Entitytwo.id  = null knowing thats it present on The BDTO .Other field are mapped correctly not included in entity code and they are mapped automatically this only for this associated field
object**
**I have the entity like :**

```
public class EntityOne implements Serializable {
    private BigDecimal id;
    private EntityTwo entityTwo;    
}
```

**and Entity1BDTO :**

```
public class EntityOneBDTO implements Serializable {
    private BigDecimal id;
    private BigDecimal entityTwo;  // Its EntityTwo.id   
}
```

My mapper Class :

```
public class EntityOneBDTO ToEntityOne extends PropertyMap<EntityOneBDTO , EntityOne >{
    
    

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        
        map().setId(source.getId());
        
    
        map().getEntityTwo().setId(source.getEntityTwo());

        skip().setgetEntityTwo(null);  // to skip other field of object
```

it returns with the error

```
1) Failed to set value '1' on model.EntityOne.setEntityTwo() // i want to set it to EntityOne.EntityTwo.id
```

Thank you in advance